# Список файлов в каталоге linux

Tags: bash, linux

Какая есть команда bash чтобы получить список файлов в некотором каталоге? причем нужны их полный адреса, а не только названия. И только это. Без указания прав доступа и прочей информации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) с помощью find

```
find `pwd` -mindepth 1
find <folder> -mindepth 1

find `pwd`/*
find <folder>/*
```

2) с помощью ls

```
ls | xargs -n 1 -i echo "`pwd`/{}"
ls <folder> | xargs -n 1 -i echo "<folder>/{}"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Правда тот же find когда список файлов выводит, то сначала пишет и сам каталог, по которому идет поиск. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы он не выводился?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tree -i -f -L 1
```

f — выводить полные пути, 
L — уровень вложенности

Если нужно обрезать родительский каталог и итоговый вывод, то:

```
$ tree -i -f -L 1 | head -n -2 | tail -n +2
```